# Not able to sign cod file in blackberry

Tags: code-signing, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install the signing keys which i have recieved from RIM.I have install them successfully on my workstation,but when i am trying to to sign my any cod file.it gives error

**"Unable to Request signatures  until this application has been registered with all signing authorities required"**

i am not understanding which steps i have missed.please help me out.
Thanks,
Sagar.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have 3 keys installed in your system. RIM provides 3 certificates. install all of them. same process followed to all of them. then restart eclipse or system if required. sure it will work.